# yii using named parameters

Tags: php, yii

I'm having issues changing Id param to name  or title parameters

I have a URL Manager that looks like this below, which receives parameters like http://example.com/user/1

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName'=>false,
        'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),
```

and then i changed it to something like this below, which is suppose to receive parameters like http://example.com/user/peter , but its not working

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName'=>false,
        'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<title:([A-Za-z0-9-]+)>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),
```

And i know, i'm doing something wrong here

Answer (score 0):

```
<controller:\w+>/<title:\w+>'=>'<controller>/view
```

this must help